# Mahout+Hadoop on Windows

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mahout, large-data, bigdata

I want to use large scale machine learning algoritms and I want to use Mahout for this task, but it seems Mahout depends on Hadoop and Hadoop is distributed only as Lunix packages.

Is there any way to use Mahout\Hadoop on Windows?

Or maybe someone can suggest some alternatives?

Comment: http://hortonworks.com/partners/microsoft/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple Hadoop vendors already. Hortonworks is one of them and released a version of their platform on Windows: [HDP on Windows](http://hortonworks.com/partners/microsoft/).
Mahout should be able to run on top of this!

Alternatively there is also [Datameer](http://www.datameer.com/), which you have to pay for (except you coming from academia) with their [Smart Analytics](http://www.datameer.com/product/smart-analytics.html) feature!

Comment: Hortonworks will work only for Windows Server 2008 and 2012?What if I want to run it on my local computer (Win 7)?

Comment: The is also the chance to run plain Apache Hadoop (or any other distribution like the Hortonworks one) on cygwin. See https://gist.github.com/tariqmislam/2159173 for instructions!